# updating a database record with linq to sql in c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a function that looks like this:

```
public UpdateRecord(MyObjectModel TheObject, int TheUserID)
{
  using (MyDataContextModel TheDC = new MyDataContextModel())
  {
     var TheObjectInDB = (from o in TheDC.TheObjects
                          where o.ObjectID == TheObject.ObjectID
                          select new MyObjectModel()).SingleOrDefault();

     if (TheObject.Prop1 != null) { TheObjectInDB.Prop1 = TheObject.Prop1; }
     if (TheObject.Prop2 != null) { TheObjectInDB.Prop2 = TheObject.Prop2; }

     TheDC.SubmitChanges();
  }
}
```

The code is not crashing but it's not updating the DB. What do I need to change?

Comment: Maybe `TheObjectInDB` returns null?

Comment: This looks like a `SELECT` statement to me, so why _should_ it be `UPDATE`ing the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select o instead of new MyObjectMode(), Modify:

```
var TheObjectInDB = (from o in TheDC.TheObjects
                          where o.ObjectID == TheObject.ObjectID
                          select o).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Oh duh!! Thanks for the answer, I got!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you do `select new MyObjectModel()` in your query which will always create a new object regardsess of what you pull from the database. Change that to `select o`.

Secondly, in:

```
if (TheObject.Prop1 != null) { TheObjectInDB.Prop1 = TheObject.Prop1; }
if (TheObject.Prop2 != null) { TheObjectInDB.Prop2 = TheObject.Prop2; }
```

you update the object's values conditionally. So if `Prop1` and `Prop2` are null the object's properties won't be updated.

Comment: "So if Prop1 and Prop2 are null the object's properties won't be updated." Yes, that's what I'm looking to do: if Prop1 AND Prop2 are empty then no update and if Prop1 has a new value but Prop2 is empty then only update Prop1. Is that going to cause problems?

Comment: @frenchie No, it shouldn't cause problems, but the first part obviously does.

Comment: ok, cool. I did make the change and it was select o!! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works and it is almost the same as what you posted.

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
var q = from a in dc.GetTable<Employee>()
        where a.EmployeeID == this.EmployeeID
        select a;
Employee temp = q.Single<Employee>();
temp.EmployeeActiveStatus = this.EmployeeActiveStatus;
temp.EmployeeName = this.EmployeeName;
temp.EmployeeUserID = this.EmployeeUserID;
temp.EmployeeCreateModifyDate = this.EmployeeCreateModifyDate;
temp.EmployeePaperWork = this.EmployeePaperWork;
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

The only major difference that I see is the line:
    select new MyObjectMode()).SingleOrDefault()